# Bootstrap 5 Carousel Play and Pause button

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5

I can't seem to get this carousel to do what I want. Can some one help me out? There are most likely a few things wrong here, believe me I know.

I would like to have the carousel play on load, and have a pause/play button to control it.

I have tried, and for some reason I cannot seem to get the button to pause on "pause" click, and resume play when "play" clicked.

Can anyone please see what I am doing incorrectly?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function() {
var paused = 0;
var carouselElement = document.getElementById("home-carousel");
var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(carouselElement, {
    interval: 100,
    pause: 0
  });
});
    
  /* Play trigger */
 $("button#toggleCarousel").click(function() {
    var state = (paused) ? "'cycle'" : "'pause'";
    paused = (paused) ? 0 : 1;
    $('#home-carousel').carousel(state);
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-play-circle fa-pause-circle');
  });
  });
```

```css
.carousel-control-prev {
  bottom: 65px;
  right: 50vw;
}
.carousel-control-next {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 65px;
}
.carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background: 0 0;
  border: 0;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity .15s ease;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23fff'%3e%3cpath d='M11.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  left: 20vw;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
}
.carousel-control-next-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23fff'%3e%3cpath d='M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
  right: 20vw;
}
.carousel-indicators {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
img.img-1 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 64% 60px;
  background-color: #2e3138;
}
img.img-2 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 64% 60px;
  background-color: #2e3138;
}
img.img-3 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 64% 60px;
  background-color: #2e3138;
}
img.img-4 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 64% 60px;
  background-color: #2e3138;
}
img.img-5 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 64% 60px;
  background-color: #2e3138;
}
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 15%;
  margin-top: 7rem;
  margin-left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js" integrity="sha256-a9jBBRygX1Bh5lt8GZjXDzyOB+bWve9EiO7tROUtj/E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b4846099d0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="toggleCarousel"><i class="fas fa-pause-circle" style="color: #ff0000;"></i></button>
<div id="home-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active text d-flex align-items-center" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1">
        <img src="assets/images/icons/start-a-new-fleet-icon.png" class="d-none d-md-block" style="height:40px;">Start a new fleet</button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" class="text d-flex align-items-center" aria-label="Slide 2">
        <img src="assets/images/icons/transfer-an-existing-fleet-icon.png" class="d-none d-md-block" style="height:40px;">Transfer an existing fleet</button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" class="text d-flex align-items-center" aria-label="Slide 3">
        <img src="assets/images/icons/electric-bolt-icon.png" class="d-none d-md-block" style="height:40px;">Electrify your fleet</button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide-to="3" class="text d-flex align-items-center" aria-label="Slide 4">
        <img src="assets/images/icons/car-key-icon.png" class="d-none d-md-block" style="height:40px;">Get a Novated lease</button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://s3-alpha.figma.com/hub/file/948140848/1f4d8ea7-e9d9-48b7-b70c-819482fb10fb-cover.png" class="img-1 w-100 d-block" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h5 class="carousel-header"><span class="text-red">Start</span><span class="text-caps"> a new fleet</span></h5>
        <p class="carousel-txt">
            A getting started guide<br><br>
            <a class="btn btn-bd-light" href="#" role="button">Find out more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://s3-alpha.figma.com/hub/file/948140848/1f4d8ea7-e9d9-48b7-b70c-819482fb10fb-cover.png" class="img-2 w-100 d-block" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h5 class="carousel-header"><span class="text-red">Transfer</span><span class="text-caps"> an existing fleet</span></h5>
        <p class="carousel-txt">
            Bring your current fleet over to Custom Fleet!<br><br>
            <a class="btn btn-bd-light" href="#" role="button">Get started</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://s3-alpha.figma.com/hub/file/948140848/1f4d8ea7-e9d9-48b7-b70c-819482fb10fb-cover.png" class="img-3 w-100 d-block" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h5 class="carousel-header"><span class="text-green">Electrify</span><span class="text-caps"> your fleet</span></h5>
        <p class="carousel-txt">
            The future of fleet is not the internal combustion engine – it's electric<br><br>
            <a class="btn btn-bd-green" href="#" role="button">Contact us</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://s3-alpha.figma.com/hub/file/948140848/1f4d8ea7-e9d9-48b7-b70c-819482fb10fb-cover.png" class="img-4 w-100 d-block" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h5 class="carousel-header"><span class="text-caps">Get a </span><span class="text-red">Novated lease</span></h5>
        <p class="carousel-txt">
            Get your dream car and save a bundle<br><br>
            <a class="btn btn-bd-light" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
     <button class="carousel-control-prev d-block d-md-none" type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next d-block d-md-none" type="button" data-bs-target="#home-carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>

</div>
```